# Read PDF content without download PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Is there a way to read the contents of a PDF document from a URL without saving it locally?
I need to make a request to a PDF document on the website, for example [www.document.com/1.pdf](http://www.document.com/1.pdf)
and read its contents into a variable without fetching the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that with `file_get_contents`.

```
$pdfContent = file_get_contents('http://www.document.com/1.pdf');
echo $pdfContent;
```

Then you have the content in a variable. But you have to patient that you don't run over your memory limit.